# Is TTF format enough for using a web font in a project?

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts, truetype

My client sent me his desired fonts for using in his project, but it only contains TTF format. Now I want to know is that enough to just load TTF format for my project web fonts ?
How much browser support I'll get by just using TTF format ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is a genuine client, then you will have to inform them that they need to supply you with the WOFF versions of these fonts instead. There are lots of hilarious license issues around using a full system font on the web (because anyone can just grab them from their browser cache and install them in their OS. Yay, you just unwittingly illegally distributed the font), and many foundries have separate licenses for using their typefaces online. Insure yourself: have your client supply known-to-be-legal-online fonts instead.

Comment: As the font is Free, the Licensing is not an issue @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans . The only consideration for now is just Browser Support.

Comment: the WOFF is still going to be the format of choice - especially if the font is free, it's a good bet there's already a WOFF version available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TTF is supported pretty much everywhere except Opera Mini and partial support in IE. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf)

Comment: this is actually quite untrue, with MS browsers apply extremely strict parsing to `ttf` and `otf` fonts based on the OpenType `fsType` bits in the OS/2 table. Using `WOFF`, the wrapper container that packs `ttf`/`otf` as specifically intended for the web, is a far better choice. `ttf`/`otf` for system fonts, WOFF for web content.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Do you think using services on https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-woff2 to convert TTF to WOFF2 will do the work for me ?

Comment: I never trust these, myself, because they're typically pretty terrible at how they effect conversion. My personal choice is to grab the free, open source [fontforge](https://fontforge.github.io] and convert the font with that.

Comment: @startToday actually everythingfonts.com seems to use fontforge & google woff2 converter for this as backends depending the input font. I would certainly trade the ease of one click use and so far I got the best conversion results from that site.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not. `ttf` is a **universal OpenType font** (with glyph outlines using the TrueType vector instruction set, and `otf` is *the same type of font* just with glyph outlines described using the Type2 vector instruction set), and subject to way stricter parsing than if you take that `ttf` and then pack it as a `WOFF` instead, which explicitly marks it as intended for use on the web, with certain things that *need* to be in a system font entirely omitted in web context.

**Do not use `ttf`/`otf`.**

###### "If it's the same thing, and everything supports TTF, why do I need to pack it as WOFF? That's more effort!"

Sort of, but there are plenty of free utils that'll do the conversion for you, and it's a font: you convert it once. Then you're done for the next few years. That's not really effort, just a one time act.